# SQL MySQL query joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the structure below.

Table: Contact

```
Id, Name, Email, PrimaryPhone, Description, CompanyId*
```

Table: Company

```
Id*, Name, Email, Description
```

I would like a query to return the:

```
Contact.Name, Contact.Email, Contact.PrimaryPhone, Company.Name, Company.Email, Contact.Description. Company.Description, Contact.CompanyName

WHERE Contact.Name Like '%x%' or Company.Name LIKE '%x%'
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Contact.Name, Contact.Email, Contact.PrimaryPhone, Company.Name, 
    Company.Email, Contact.Description. Company.Description, Contact.CompanyName
FROM Contact
RIGHT JOIN Company ON Company.Id = Contact.CompanyId
WHERE Contact.Name LIKE '%x%' OR Company.Name LIKE '%x%'
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem, I have information in the Company table which is not in the Contact table, so, there is no relation between them so they are not being returned. Is there a way to return the value in these cases?

Comment: edited the query to a right join so you get all results from the compamny table regardless of whether they have a contact

Comment: it perfectly worked! Thanks! It looks easy but just after you guide me! Really appreciated!

Comment: If you really appreciate it, mark @naw103 's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.Name, C.Email, C.PrimaryPhone, C.Name, CO.Email, C.Description. CO.Description, C.CompanyName
FROM Company AS CO
LEFT JOIN Contact AS C ON CO.CompanyId=C.CompanyId
WHERE C.Name LIKE '%x%' OR CO.Name LIKE '%x%'
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem, I have information in the Company table which is not in the Contact table, so, there is no relation between them so they are not being returned. Is there a way to return the value in these cases?